# 61, 72, 88 keys for music covers and some classics? Suggestions for a traveler?

Tags: piano, keyboard, digital-piano

Alright, so I'm a really beginner. Looking forward to practice and play piano.
I'd like to play mostly pop songs covers for example: "Let it go, Boom clap" and stuff like that also kpop. And some pretty famous classics, not a lot. How many keys do I need for that?

I'm also a traveler, I travel twice or 3 times a year, I don't stay in one country, so it'd be pretty hard for me to carry a 88 keys on plane everytime I fly. So for that, any suggestions for light keyboards?

Also what do you think of silicon? I really don't feel that they'd be pretty nice, as they don't really feel real or anything.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by silicon?

Comment: The rubber digital usb piano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are a beginner and just starting to learn various arrangements of the songs you want to play, you should be able to use a 61 key keyboard and derive plenty of enjoyment.  You won't be able to play the composers arrangements of classical standards, but that does not sound like your goal.

61 keys gives you enough keys to play a bass line or some chords with your left hand and play the melody and/or counterpoint with your right.  Some keyboards allow for transposing or shifting of the tuning in a split keyboard arrangement to give you a wider range on 61 keys.

The fact that you want to carry your instrument on a plane is a big reason that I feel the 61 key version should be strongly considered.  That is probably the only size that you might have a chance at carrying on and stowing in the overhead compartment of an airplane.  I fly with a guitar and carry it on.  And my 61 key Casio keyboard is shorter than my guitar.  So I'm thinking maybe ...

If you can get a keyboard that will fit in a padded keyboard soft bag that can qualify as carry on luggage, then I would go that route and carry it on so you can keep an eye on it.  If you end up with a keyboard that is too big to carry on, invest in a sturdy, hardshell, flight case and consider insurance if it's available.  The baggage handlers can be pretty rough, tossing your keyboard around.

Play different keyboards to see how they feel to you.  They all vary from make to make and within brands, there may be different offerings with a different feel on the keys.  I would tend to lien towards one of the lower priced instruments that met my needs if I were going to use it as a traveler and carry it on a plane.

Most accomplished professional musicians who get paid to tour all over the country or world, have their promoters arrange to have a rental keyboard or piano delivered to each venue.  It's really hard to travel with a nine foot Steinway Grand Piano - or even a Hammond B-3 Organ.  So when you reach that level, you will be playing a full sized instrument, but will be renting it at your destination.

Have fun learning to play some songs you enjoy on a smaller keyboard.  It should work just fine for now.

Comment: Thank you for your response, really appreciated this much of information. Just one last thing, if you don't mind, before putting your response as the right one. Would 61 keys keyboard go fine with playing pop songs covers? Even the hard ones? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanSaad  You can absolutely play Pop covers with 61 keys!  Remember, when you are playing covers, nobody expects you to sound like the original artist.  You only need to create a reasonably authentic reproduction that the audience will recognize.  There may be some covers where 61 keys will not allow you to play the song like they do on the record - but you will be able to play your version - and most listeners won't know the difference.  Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to this forum. You say your travelling. I have a colleague who took out a special insurance for his keyboard. He was asked to play in a different country. When he came off the plane the keyboard was broken. In my opinion at place of destinations borrow or rent a keyboard. You will always have a better keyboard, then buying something cheap and have broken underway.